# Nothing happens on clicking login

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

I was trying to create a login page, but it doesn't seem to work. When I click Login/Signup, a popup shows. I enter details and click login. Nothing happens. I try to signup, still nothing happens.

My homepage

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Experiment on Social Network</TITLE>
<script src = "jscript.js"></script>
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "style.css" />
<script type = "text/javascript">
window.onload = function()
{
    document.getElementById("LoginBtn").onClick = sendRequest("login.php");
    document.getElementById("SignBtn").onClick = sendRequest("Signup.php");
};
</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY bgcolor = "black" text = "white" alink = "blue" vlink = "cyan">
<a href = "..//index.html">Home</a>
<div id = "responseOutput">
<a id = "logSign_pop" href = "#logSign">Login or Signup</a>
<a href = "#x" class="overlay" id="logSign"></a>
    <div class = "popup">
            <h1>Welcome Guest!</h1>
        <form action = "#">
        <h3>Login Here</h3>
        <label for = "user">Username</label>
        <br />
        <input type = "text" id = "uname" value = "" />
        <br />
        <label for = "password">Password</label>
        <br />
        <input type = "password" id = "pass" value = "" />
        <br />
        <input type="button" id = "LoginBtn" value="Log In" />
        <a class="close" href="#close"></a> 
    </form>
    <form action = "#">
        <h3>Sign Up</h3>
            <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
            <br/>
            <input type="text" id="firstName" value="" />
            <br />
            <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
            <br/>
            <input type="text" id="lastName" value="" />
            <br />
            <label for="useName">UserName</label>
            <br/>
            <input type="text" id="useName" value="" />
            <br />
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <br/>
            <input type="text" id="email" value="" />
            <br />
            <label for="pass">Password</label>
            <br/>
            <input type="password" id="pwd" value="" />
            <br />
        <input type="button" id = "SignBtn" value="Sign Up" />
        <a class="close" href="#close"></a>
    </form>
</div>
 </div>
<br/>
<center>
<h1>Welcome to MaxZeroEdge Network</h1>
</center>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

login.php

```
<?php
$logID = $_POST["uname"];
$pass = $_POST["pass"];
$login = 0;
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","admin","admin");
    if (!$con)
        {
            die('Could not connect to database: '. mysql_error());
        }

    $db = mysql_select_db("logDat", $con);
    if(!$db)
    {
        create_db();
    }

    $tb = "SELECT * from logDat";
    $av = @mysql_query($tb);
    if(!$av)
    {
        echo "Error creating database: " . mysql_error();
    }
    else
    {
        checkLogin();
    }

function checkLogin()
    {
        //Checks if a particular value exists
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM logDat");
        //$passResult = mysql_query("SELECT password FROM logDat");
        $check = $logID;
        while($login == 0 && $row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            if($row["Username"] == $logID)
            {
                if($row["password"] == $logPass)
                {
                    /*$login = 1;
                    $expire = 86400*7;
                    setcookie("user",$logID,$expire);*/
                    $_SESSION["userid1"] = $logID;
                    print "<message>Welcome $logID</message>";
                    //header("Location: Social Network.php"); // redirects
                }
                else echo "Incorrect Password.";
            }
            else echo "User doesn't exist.";
        }
    }

    //Runs for the first time only. Creates the database    

    function create_db()
    {
        if (mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE logDat",$con))
        {
            echo "Database created";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Error creating database: " . mysql_error();
        }
    }   

//Runs for the first time only. Creates the table.

    function create_table()
    {
        //Password varchar(20),
        $user = "CREATE TABLE logDat
        (
            personID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            PRIMARYKEY(personID),
            Username varchar(20),
            FirstName varchar(50),
            LastName varchar(50),
            Email varchar(100),
            password varchar(20);
        )";
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO logDat(PRIMARYKEY, Username, FirstName, LastName, Email, password) VALUES(0, 'zero', 'Palash', 'Max', 'maxzeroedge@gmail.com', 'hellfire') ");
    }

mysql_close($con);  
?>
```

Comment: Right now you are pulling all current users then looping over them in code until you find one that matches your login attempt. That's going to become extremely slow as your userbase grows.  You ought to be querying for the existence of the requested username and password (and you need to be salting+hashing the password rather than storing plain text!!!) in a `WHERE` clause.  Finally, the `mysql_*()` functions are deprecated and will be removed in a future version of PHP.  It is  wise to start learning an API supporting prepared statements, like [PDO](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: But anyway, where is the JavaScript which defines the function `sendRequest()`? That is what should be performing the action here and is nowhere in sight.

Comment: It was just a hobby project, so I didn't really think about safety. Thanks for the heads up, though.
BTW, I didn't get 
 "querying for the existence of the requested username and password in a WHERE clause"
Can you explain?

And the sendrequest is this
try { netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalBrowserRead");} catch (e) {}
 var xhr = createXHR();
 if(xhr)
 {
  xhr.open("POST", link, true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange(function() {handleResponse(xhr)});
  xhr.send(null);
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove javascript `window.onload` function

Use input type `submit` for button and add targated page to `action`

As:

```
<form action = "login.php" method='post'>

<input type="submit" id = "LoginBtn" value="Log In" />
```

Instead of

```
<form action = "#">

<input type="button" id = "LoginBtn" value="Log In" />
```

Same thing for Sugn Up portion

Comment: Thanks, turns out it was submit instead of button.